# excel formula search to calculate the below if possible

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I’ve got a query if someone can help.

An accumulation of 20 points equals one 1 credit.

If there is one person with 10 points another with 5 and another with an additional 5. The total of the 3 makes 20 so another credit.

Assuming I have a pot of say 500 credit I am trying to give away is there a formula which would make it easier to calculate

Essentially every 20 point we deduct 1?

[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: please mock up the data set and expected output.  Then [edit] your question and include that table mock up.

Comment: @ScottCraner Done. I think I am over complicating it? I can get the result by tallying the total of 'point' dividing this by the 20 and substrate from the pot

Comment: `=A2-INT(SUM(B5:B14)/20)`

Comment: Prefect! Thank you!